# DNS responses from ISP are slower and slower, solution?

Tags: domain-name-system, isp

Using a LAN with Linux boxes.

The responses from the ISP are slower and slower. There is no special reason for that locally, all machines experience the delays. The router did not change / neither the traffic.

I'm thinking of installing a machine with `bind` `named` to `cache` the DNS responses. All other boxes would `resolve` from that local server.

Three questions

- Should I try to use the local DNS server to send requests directly to the `root` servers?
- Or should I simply use the `forwarders` (to ISP NS servers)?
- Any better idea, maybe, than installing a local `bind` server?

**edit**

Thanks for your inputs - don't we have privacy implications when using an external name server? This is also true for my local ISP, but the scale is much smaller.
For instance, Google knows already a lot - using their DNS would tell them **all** the sites visited...
Or am I becoming paranoid ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend trying a different nameserver.  You can find out which one is best for you using [namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/). This runs tests against various public nameservers to find which one is ideal for your location/connection.

Or you can just try google at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: In this case, installing locally a `bind` to cache the new name servers responses wouldn't hurt?

Comment: Discovered namebench the other day, it's just awesome.

Comment: @ring0: Nope that is not a bad idea.  In fact if you are not caching with linux every single query will take an extra 5 seconds to failover to the second server in `resolv.conf`.

Comment: And what about privacy concerns (**edit** of the question)?

Answer (score 3):

Any possibility of falling back to OpenDNS or Google DNS?

When I was in university, my dorm-provided connection had the same issues. I ran TreeWalk for a long time, which was nice. I fell back on OpenDNS later and mostly haven't looked back since.

Answer (score 2):

Bind as caching DNS server is overkill. My favorite is [pdnsd](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~rombouts/pdnsd.html).

Answer (score 2):

Personally (since this is actually what I do) I'd go for the local caching resolver option (either BIND or [Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/)) *without* forwarders and enable DNSSEC.

This will:

1. give you DNSSEC even though your ISP probably doesn't support it (yet), hence:
2. prevent your ISP from pulling [Stupid DNS Tricks](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1647302) on you (e.g. NXDOMAIN rewriting)

Answer (score 1):

- It's up to you if you use forwarders like the [free 4.2.2.2 to 4.2.2.4 or Google's 8.8.8.8](http://theos.in/windows-xp/free-fast-public-dns-server-list/).
- Forwarders may give better performance, but will depend on how you have caching configured and the particular DNS servers involved.
- It might be simpler to point your computers at a publicly available DNS server like the ones listed above, than to run your own BIND server.

Answer (score -2):

You could also try dnscache. There are examples on the official website for it as well, which might be useful. http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/dnscache.html